# Using Radio Buttons to hide div's with multiple layers

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, show-hide

I am well aware that using the Show/Hide function has been answered when it comes to radio buttons but I have searched high and low for a solution to my problem. What I am attempting to do is create a form where a visitor has a couple of options to choose from, they click one of said options, it displays a hidden div and inside that div it gives the visitor more options to choose from. This is where I run into the issue. What I would like to do is have the first hidden div that becomes displayed to stay shown after one of the options inside of that div is selected to display what that button is hiding.

Here is the jfiddle for what I'm currently working on - http://jsfiddle.net/UDEQZ/

Here is the html

```
<input name="pagetype" type="radio" onclick="show(0)" />First
<input name="pagetype" type="radio" onclick="show(1)" />Second
<input name="pagetype" type="radio" onclick="show(2)" />Third
<p></p>
<div id="d0" class="CF" style="display:none;">Select One:
<p></p>
<input name="pagetype" type="radio" onclick="show(3)" />One
<input name="pagetype" type="radio" onclick="show(4)" />Two
<input name="pagetype" type="radio" onclick="show(5)" />Three
<input name="pagetype" type="radio" onclick="show(6)" />Four
<input name="pagetype" type="radio" onclick="show(7)" />Five
<input name="pagetype" type="radio" onclick="show(8)" />Six
<input name="pagetype" type="radio" onclick="show(9)" />Seven</div>
<div id="d1">Two</div>
<div id="d2">Three</div>
<div id="d3">Hazaa</div>
<div id="d4">Bazinga</div>
<div id="d5">Hazaa</div>
<div id="d6">Bazinga</div>
<div id="d7">Hazaa</div>
<div id="d8">Bazinga</div>
<div id="d9">Hazaa</div>
```

And here is the script I'm using

```
function show(number) {
"use strict";
var el, i = 0;
while (el = document.getElementById("d" + (i++))) {
    el.style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById('d' + number).style.display = "block";
}
```

For the HTML one thing I attempted that, to me, should have worked was with the `onclick="show(3)"` I changed it to `onclick="show(0, 3)"` But when you clicked on the radio button with One next to it, nothing happened.

I'm still new to javascript/jquery and I've seen show/hide being used for a lot of the radio button questions asked but I have yet to see a solution or even a question pertaining to the problem that I am having. I've tried a few different options, running it through an array(still kinda going huh? on that one haha), using the show/hide function, and multiple other ways that have been described on here and other sites. For some reason I feel as if the solution is extremely simple and I've just been too daft to see it posted or skipped right over it.

Comment: if I well understood : to get the attribute of an `elem` use `elem.getAttribute("checked")`. to check wether an `elem` is checked or not use `elem.checked`, see the doc http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: Newben, Even though its not exactly what I was looking for I still appreciate the response and will re-read the doc at a more leisurely pace to better expand my knowledge. Thank You =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since jquery is tagged i am using jquery to reduce you code..

```
function show(number) {

  $('[id^="d"]').hide();
  if(number >=3){
    $('#d0').show();
  }
  $('#d' + number).show();
}
```

however this is cosidering all you other div such as `d3,d4,d5,d6..` comes under `d0`..
what i am doing here is using a attribute selector `$('[id^="d"]')` which select all element ids starting with `d` and hiding it... so this hide all the elements.. and then checkin if the number parameter is > 3 ..if its greater than 3 then , show `#d0` element.., then show just the element whose id is = `number`

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UDEQZ/5/)

Comment: Ahh success! Thank You bipen! I have jquery tagged because I have been looking all over the place and I knew that for this particular problem jquery would more then likely be the answer. With it checking if the number is >3, would it cause an error if I decide to hide d0-2 instead of having them being shown?

Comment: the if condition is there just to make sure when cliked on  radios with values as one,two,three... the first `<div id="d0"..` (itself)..does not hides... `$('#d0').show();`..this means show the div  whose id is `d0`

Comment: Sorry, I miss read my own code haha. Its been a long day.. So let me try this again, with it being >3 when the number is <3 it hides everything that has a value greater then 3 correct?

Comment: Yes, After I read your edit it clicked. The if function is calling out for any div greater then 3, d0 stays shown, while d1 and d2 being checked, d0 is hidden again.

Comment: Now time to expand this even more and incorporating more beginning options and then adding options to each starting option. Would it be beneficial, in your opinion, to create a new function for each option(ie one for the First radio button, Second, and Third)?

Comment: its better if you handle all the options with one function (work on one fuction so that this works for all)... rather then creating each function for each option ..just think..what if you have to add 10 more option in near future that means you end up adding 10 more functions...and again 20 options more later... hehe  :)

Comment: Oh dear haha. Yea. That would potentially be a nightmare. The only reason I was thinking of using a different function for each one was to break it up and be easier to read, granted not easier to code per say but for someone following me they would be able to look at it and go okay I see whats going on here even without looking at all the comments

Comment: hmmmm your are rite .. :) seperating functions is more clear and readable and easy to understand... but i am a.. write less, do more.. kind of a guy .. :) :).. so anyways itz fine if you seperate the function.. i don't think that will create issue(performance wise..jus that you would be writing a litle more codes) ..and evenif it does that will be negligiable and unnoticeable..so you should go with what suits you..

Comment: I will go ahead and do that since the form I'm working on it would be best to have everything separated and easy to read more so when I myself have to go back into it to change something or add something I wont go o.O what the.. But thank you again bipen =D